# How do I generate random sentences through lists of different lengths?

Tags: python, list

I am making an anniversary present for my boyfriend and I want to send him a program that gives him a different reason why I love him every time it runs (he studies computer science and it would be fitting).

After research, I know I want it to do this after I say print:
"Reason why I love [nickname]: [Reason why I love him]

There would be 6 nicknames and 100 reasons and I want it to give return one sentence each time it runs!

I appreciate any help <3

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: This isn't really the typical stackoverflow question format but I think its an exception lol, I'd start with a list of sentences like `reasons = ['Not bald', 'No facial hair', ...] then you can select a random item from that list

Comment: This is so cute and I can't stop smiling :) I would like to help you but I think your boyfriend would be a lot happier if you can figure it out yourself :D

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a design or coding resource.  The application is cute, but it's quite off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

happy anniversary! i suggest using the `random.choice()` method:

```
import random
def print_sentence(nicknames, reasons):
    print("Reason why I love {0}: {1}".format(random.choice(nicknames), random.choice(reasons)))

def main():
    nicknames = ["bob", "john", "George"]
    reasons = ["just 'cause", "his smile"]
    print_sentence(nicknames, reasons)
```

will print for example `Reason why I love bob: just 'cause`

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! Would this work even if one list is longer than the other?

Comment: yes. the function **choice()** randomly chooses one element from the list (or any other iterable) you pass to it and returns it, so the length of the list is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

using the `random` library, you can have it select a random element from a sequence.
For example:

```
import random
nicknames = ["Nick", "Brian", "Bob", "Fred", "Jeremy", "David"]
print(random.choice(nicknames))
```

This code will print a random name from the list `nicknames` every time it is run. You may wish to change the nicknames to something slightly more endearing for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

My wife + wine =

```py
import random

nicknames = [
    'Panda Bear',
    'My Love Love',
    'White Chocolate'
]

reasons = [
    'the way you look at me',
    'your eyes',
    'your kisses',
    'your cheesy jokes',
    'your soft pinkish lips',
    'your ear lobes'
]

def get_message(name_list, reason_list):
    name = random.choice(name_list)
    reason = random.choice(reason_list)
    return f'Reason why I love {name}: {reason}.'

# print one random reason
print(get_message(nicknames, reasons))

# print ten random reasons for fun
for n in range(10):
    print(get_message(nicknames, reasons))
```

Output:

```
Reason why I love Panda Bear: your cheesy jokes.
Reason why I love Panda Bear: your kisses.
Reason why I love My Love Love: your soft pinkish lips.
Reason why I love My Love Love: the way you look at me.
Reason why I love White Chocolate: your cheesy jokes.
Reason why I love White Chocolate: the way you look at me.
Reason why I love My Love Love: the way you look at me.
Reason why I love White Chocolate: your kisses.
Reason why I love White Chocolate: your soft pinkish lips.
Reason why I love My Love Love: your soft pinkish lips.
Reason why I love Panda Bear: your ear lobes.
```

You can add your own reasons and nicknames separated by a comma and wrapped in quotes.